# MySQL - return when row doesn't exists in other table or exists and the field is greater than x

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

links

```
 | id | ...
   1
   2
  ...
```

clicks

```
 | linkid | userid | click_date |
    1     |   2    | ...
    4     |   2    | ...
    5     |   3    | ...
```

When users clicks a link from links it is added to clicks.

I want to use MySQL query to return only links that user hasn't clicked - the pair linkid:userid isn't contained in the table or click_date (secs from Unix epoch) was yesterday in GMT.

Comment: BTW. This is PHP script, I can use any PHP functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT links_clicks.linkid FROM
(SELECT links.id AS linkid 
 FROM links 
 LEFT JOIN clicks ON links.id = clicks.linkid
 WHERE links.id IS NULL OR clicks.click_date <= CURDATE())
 AS links_clicks;
```

Comment: This will return all collumns from both tables, yes?

Is this possible to return only collumns from links?

Comment: This will lead me to making two queries, if this possible I want only one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN operation. I'm not sure about the condition of the WHERE statement, you might have to modify that.

```
SELECT id FROM links
JOIN
SELECT linkid FROM clicks WHERE (userid IS null)
```

Execute the SQL query with the PHP Mysql module.

For example

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$query = "THE SQL STATEMENT FROM ABOVE";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: This will only return links that weren't NEVER clicked by user.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward query:

```
select * from link
where id not in (
    select linkid 
    from clicks
    where userid = $userid
    and click_date >= current_date)
```

This inner query find all links that have been clicked by the user *today*, and the `not in (...)` syntax means you *won't* get these links.

This query gives exactly what the question asks for.

Comment: I've stated: only links that haven't been clicked today.

Comment: That what this does! Those links the user has clicked today are **NOT** in the results of the outer query via the `not in (...)` syntax.

Comment: Oh, works... But the answer marked by me works faster on my table.

Answer (score 0):

the sql select to selects all links that user with given #userid hasn't clicked:

```
select * from links where id not in( select linkid from clicks where userid = #userid)
```

and selects all clicks that user clicks yesterday

```
select * from links a inner join clicks b on(a.id = b.linkid) where date(click_date) = date(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) and userid = #userid
```

and if you wants it together

```
select * from links where id not in( select linkid from clicks where userid = #userid) or 
id in(select linkid from clicks where date(click_date) = date(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) and userid = #userid)
```